# Chrome bug: automatically add style="margin-bottom: 18px;" on body element

Tags: html, css

I didn't apply any inline style on my `<body>` element. But when I inspect the DOM, it shows `<body cz-shortcut-listen="true" style="margin-bottom: 18px;">`.

I tried to apply inline style on my body element and set `margin-bottom` to 0, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show an example of when it doesn't respect? Because, there's a User Agent StyleSheet and you need to reset it using your CSS.

Comment: That sounds like an extension. Can you disable your browser extensions and trying again?

Comment: @Gershom You're right! After I disabled "Auto Replay for YouTube" extension, the bottom margin disappears. I have a background video on my site and I think that's why it adds a bottom margin. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this to set all margin to 0

```
*{margin: 0;}
```

Comment: This won't work, as the `*` selector won't override inline styles.